# Can a decorator be working with a lambda expression at runtime?

Tags: python, lambda, decorator

```
def attrs(**kwds):
      def decorate(f):
          for k in kwds:
              setattr(f, k, kwds[k])
          return f
      return decorate

@attrs(argument_types=(int, int,), returns=int)
def add(a, b):
      return a + b
```

Here I need the add() can be with the ability to show its acceptable parameter type.
but can I do something like this in runtime?

```
ladd=[]
for x in range(0,10):

      @attrs(argument_types=int, returns=int,default_parameter1 = x) 
      exp =  lambda : add(a,x)  
      ladd.append(exp)
```

or

```
ladd=[]
for x in range(0,10):

      @attrs(argument_types=int, returns=int,default_parameter1 = x) 
      addx = functools.partial(add, 2)  
      ladd.append(addx)
```

I need those function can be generated runtime with the "decoratored" parameter bind either

---

Well, here is the error information, I think above code can not work, but I never tried to paste it to python to test it...

```
>>> ladd=[]
>>> for x in range(0,10):
...     @attrs(argument_types=int, returns=int,default_parameter1 = x) 
...     exp =  lambda : add(a,x)  
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    exp =  lambda : add(a,x)  
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     ladd.append(exp)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ladd.append(exp)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
```

Comment: When you tried it, what errors did you get?

Comment: @S.Lott: While error messages are very useful in general and should be included when in doubt, anyone with enough Python knowledge to answer this should know very well that this is a plain ol' syntax error.

Comment: @delnan: The question was not for "anyone with enough Python knowledge to answer" but for @user478514 to update the question with more information, perhaps doing some real debugging work on their own.  You're right, of course, but sometimes people are helped by simply providing documentation of what they're seeing.

Comment: @S.Lott: thanks for point out, I think you means I should test it before I paste here. in this case I do not think above "code" may works so I never test it, actually, that is just a "what-if" idea in my mind.

Comment: @user478514: "what if" questions are kind of silly, aren't they?  You can try it more easily than you can ask about trying it.  After you've tried then (a) you have code you can post and (b) you have an error message we can discuss.  That's far better than a vague discussion of a random what-if.

Comment: @S.Lott: yes, you are absolutely right on the manner of asking the technical question. but, no hard means I think you may also consider the amateurs or the beginner - such as me, just in thinking how to use the python solve the problem on spare time. the first thing I want to know is "how to" when I confused or get a "what-if" in mind, then is to search "why" by RTFM or posting on the net seeking help.

Comment: by delnan and Jochens' post I now know more details about the decorator, so later I may considering a bit more deeper. BTW, That PC have no python environment when I post, by reading your comment I installed one, ignored the owner's protest totally.

Comment: @user478514: Confused is not "what if".  Confused means you have code which confuses you.  "What if" is silly because it's much easier to actually **do** something with the code and actually **see** what happens that do anything else.  Here's the hint:  **try things first**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Decorator syntax is merely syntactic sugar, albeit one that directs people's thoughts into interesting directions.

```
@expr
def f(...):
    ...
```

is identical to

```
def f(...):
    ...
f = expr(f)
```

So you can just use `attrs(argument_types=..., ...)(lambda: ...)`.

Answer (score 13):

The `@` syntax is just syntactic sugar for calling the decorator with the next function as it's argument. This means that

```
@deco
def func(): pass
```

is the same as

```
def func(): pass
func = deco(func)
```

So what you want is simply:

```
ladd=[]

for x in range(0,10):    
      deco = attrs(argument_types=int, returns=int,default_parameter1 = x) 
      addx = functools.partial(add, 2)
      # append the "decorated" function
      ladd.append(deco(addx))
```

Comment: @OP: as Jochen's code shows, decorators are just functions that happen to take and return other functions.